# My Sql TIME(STR_TO_DATE) function is not working

Tags: mysql, datetime

I am trying to store time value in my database,  but STR_TO DATE FUNCTION is not working in mysql but when i try it on w3school sql engine it is working fine with the same format.

```
INSERT INTO `discussions`( `Name`, `Topic`, `Author`, `Auth_ID`, `day`, `Date`, `Time`, `Activated`, `Topic_ID`) 
VALUES ('asdfgh','PCB Designing','ShahzaibAhmed',1,'Sunday','2018-10-28',Time(STR_TO_DATE( '03:57:AM', '%h:%i:%p' ) ),1,2);
```

This is the error i am getting when i try it

[image]

Also when i m changing it to date only it is working fine and inserting correctly without any errors

```
INSERT INTO `discussions`( `Name`, `Topic`, `Author`, `Auth_ID`, `day`, `Date`, `Time`, `Activated`, `Topic_ID`) 
VALUES ('asdfgh','PCB Designing','ShahzaibAhmed',1,'Sunday','2018-10-28',Time(STR_TO_DATE( '20120801', '%Y%m%d' ) ),1,2)
```

[image]

Comment: Also you shouldn't need to wrap the output of `STR_TO_DATE` in a `Time` function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems to be dependent on the MySQL version:

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE( '03:57:AM', '%h:%i:%p' )
```

Parses the time in [MySQL-5.6](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9eecb/61796), however not in [MySQL-5.7](https://www.db-fiddle.com/#&togetherjs=czuGpd5ne7) or [MySQL-8.0](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=9d82a3fab2aae7c0f0f0ba4778af9b1d).

[MariaDB-10.3](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=9d82a3fab2aae7c0f0f0ba4778af9b1d) and 10.2 correctly parses a result.

[MySQL bug 71386](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=71386) highlights that the [sql_mode](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html)`=NO_ZERO_DATE`, being the default in later MySQL versions, is having an effect, even though its only a time.

[MariaDB-10.3](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=cebb3d6c2801d65ed94284b4c9dddfa2) returns the correct result event when `sql_mode=NO_ZERO_DATE` is set.

So to work around your bug, disable the 'NO_ZERO_DATE' in the session before this query:

```
set session sql_mode=REPLACE(@@SESSION.sql_mode,'NO_ZERO_DATE','')
```

Comment: alternately replace the `date` and `time` columns with a combined `datetime` column and you won't hit this bug.

Comment: Thank you so much for explaining and solving sire ^^

Comment: [MySQL bug 71386](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=71386) has been corrected in 8.0.18 thanks to Oracle, me, and well you @ShahzaibAhmed for highlighting something easy to fix when I should of been doing something else. As such in 8.0.18+ versions there is no work around required (per [proof fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=9d82a3fab2aae7c0f0f0ba4778af9b1d))